# How to put Label in email using AWS SES?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-java

I have used this code to send email using AWS SES:

```
package com.amazonaws.samples;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Body;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Content;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Destination;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Message;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendEmailRequest; 

public class AmazonSESSample {
  static final String FROM = "sender@example.com";
  static final String TO = "recipient@example.com";
  static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for Java)";
  static final String HTMLBODY = "Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for Java)";
  static final String TEXTBODY = "This email was sent through Amazon SES ";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
      AmazonSimpleEmailService client = 
          AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build()
      SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest()
          .withDestination(
              new Destination().withToAddresses(TO))
          .withMessage(new Message()
              .withBody(new Body()
                  .withHtml(new Content()
                      .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(HTMLBODY))
                  .withText(new Content()
                      .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(TEXTBODY)))
              .withSubject(new Content()
                  .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(SUBJECT)))
          .withSource(FROM)
      client.sendEmail(request);
      System.out.println("Email sent!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("The email was not sent. Error message: " 
          + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Now, my problem is I have to add a label to this email such that receiver sees:

> MyLabel < @example.com>

instead of what receiver is currently seeing:

> sender@example.com

According to AWS SES's developer guide,

> You can add labels to verified email addresses without performing
> additional verification steps. To add a label to an email address, add
> a plus sign (+) between the account name and the "at" sign (@),
> followed by a text label. For example, if you already verified
> sender@example.com, you can use sender+myLabel@example.com as the
> "From" or "Return-Path" address for your emails. You can use this
> feature to implement Variable Envelope Return Path (VERP). Then you
> can use VERP to detect and remove undeliverable email addresses from
> your mailing lists.

But, if I change FROM to  "sender+MyLabel@example.com", email gets sent as:

> sender+MyLabel@example.com

Eventhough, I have verified my FROM email address. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I added label to my email by replacing my FROM variable's value from "sender@example.com" to "myLabel< sender@example.com>"

> static final String FROM = "myLabel< sender@example.com>";